# Google spreadsheet formula refer to cell with address to another cell

Tags: google-sheets

Good day! Could you please help me with the following formula. I'm trying to calculate a number of non-empty cells after specific words. 
With a formula, I defined the address of the last cells after which I need to start count. In my case, In Cell **O1** I defined the start position, for example, **A15**, the end position is always **A**. So the formula will be 
 **=COUNTA(A15:A)** 
But in my case, it could be a different start position. So, I'm trying to use formula 
**=COUNTA(CONCAT(INDIRECT(O1),":A")** 
but it does not work. Please help :)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:
=COUNTA(indirect(CONCAT(O1,":A")))